# Updating a textField when size of shape changes - JavaFX

Tags: javafx, height, nodes, textfield, shapes

Suppose I have the following:

**Creating A Rectangle(With A Top Left Handler):**

```
public Group createDraggableRectangle(double x, double y, double width, double height) {
    final double handleRadius = 20 ;
    final double handleRadius2 = 30 ;

    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);

    // top left resize handle:
    Circle resizeHandleNW = new Circle(handleRadius, Color.RED);
    resizeHandleNW.setOpacity(0);
    // bind to top left cornerof Rectangle:
    resizeHandleNW.centerXProperty().bind(rect.xProperty());
    resizeHandleNW.centerYProperty().bind(rect.yProperty());
    resizeHandleNW.setStyle("-fx-cursor: NW_RESIZE; ");

    Group group = new Group(rect, resizeHandleNW);


    Wrapper<Point2D> mouseLocation = new Wrapper<>();

    setUpDragging(resizeHandleNW, mouseLocation) ;

    resizeHandleNW.setOnMouseDragged(event -> {
        if (mouseLocation.value != null) {
            double deltaX = event.getSceneX() - mouseLocation.value.getX();
            double deltaY = event.getSceneY() - mouseLocation.value.getY();
            double newX = rect.getX() + deltaX ;
            if (newX >= handleRadius
                    && newX <= rect.getX() + rect.getWidth() - handleRadius) {
                rect.setX(newX);
                rect.setWidth(rect.getWidth() - deltaX);
            }
            double newY = rect.getY() + deltaY ;
            if (newY >= handleRadius
                    && newY <= rect.getY() + rect.getHeight() - handleRadius) {
                rect.setY(newY);
                rect.setHeight(rect.getHeight() - deltaY);
            }
            mouseLocation.value = new Point2D(event.getSceneX(), event.getSceneY());

        }
           return group;
    });
```

**Controller Class(Method For Selecting Object):**

```
@FXML
private TextField heightField;

 if (!selectedShapes.contains(shape)) {
        shape.setStyle("-fx-effect: dropshadow(three-pass-box, #cece02, 6, 6, 0, 0);");
        selectedShapes.add(shape);
        rotate.setDisable(false);
        deletebutton.setDisable(false);
    }
```

I know that writing System.out.println(rect.getHeight()) in the Rectangle class will give me the height every-time the size is changed.

However my question is that how would I add this value to the textField, held in my controller class?   I have tried various ways, however I keep getting a null pointer exception.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somewhere you presumably do

```
Group draggableRect = createDraggableRectangle(...);
```

So then you just do

```
heightField.textProperty().bind(Bindings.createStringBinding(
    () -> String.format("%.1f", draggableRect.getBoundsInLocal().getHeight()),
    draggableRect.boundsInLocalProperty());
```

or, if you want the height field's text to change in other ways (e.g. if it is editable),

```
draggableRect.boundsInLocalProperty().addListener((obs, oldBounds, newBounds) ->
    heightField.setText(String.format("%.1f", newBounds.getHeight())));
```

Comment: It Worked! Thank You! :D        (I will tick the answer in five minutes)

Comment: Hey, just a quick question, suppose I also had a rotationField to get the angle of the shape.    How would I possibly write this similarly to - rotateField.textProperty().bind(Bindings.createStringBinding(
                            () -> String.format("%.1f", group.getBoundsInLocal().getHeight()),
                            group.boundsInLocalProperty()));

Comment: @TheBeliever12 Use the `rotateProperty` (or whichever property is changing when you rotate it) instead?

Comment: Sadly, I do not know how to write this :(    But I will try and figure something out. Thanks Again.

Comment: This seems to work: group.rotateProperty().addListener((obs, oldBounds, newBounds) ->
                            rotateField.setText(String.format("%.1f", newBounds)));   Do you know how I can set it back to 0 whenever the value gets to 360.0 ?

Comment: operate '%' cannot be applied to 'java.lang.Number', int      < gave me that error

Comment: So then do `newBounds.doubleValue() % 360`

Comment: Fantastic! :) Thanks